# Having trouble removing the selected option from a picklist and reloads another picklist without the item?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, picklist

I've made a picklist that keeps on being added when click on the add option link but the javascript I'm using keeps throwing an error of cannot read property "options" of null

```
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="tableIndex" />
<apex:repeat value="{!apsList}" var="Lists">
   <div class="slds-form__row slds-m-top--x-small "
       style="margin-left: 2px;margin-right: 2px;;background-color:#ffffff;position:relative;">
       <div class="slds-form__item" role="listitem">
           <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_edit slds-hint-parent slds-form-element_horizontal">
               <!--span class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-heading_small" >Environmental Concerns<i class="fa fa-asterisk"/></span-->
               <apex:selectList id="selectedList" styleClass="slds-select" multiselect="false" size="1">
                   <apex:selectOptions id="selection" value="{!getMSPicklist}" />
               </apex:selectList>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <apex:commandLink action="{!removeList}" styleclass="slds-button slds-button_text-destructive slds-float_right"
           value="Remove option">
           <apex:param name="listId" assignTo="{!tableIndexForAction}" value="" />
       </apex:commandLink>


   </div>
   <apex:variable value="{!tableIndex+1}" var="tableIndex" />

</apex:repeat>

<div class="slds-form__item" role="listitem">
   <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_edit slds-hint-parent slds-form-element_horizontal">
       <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="AddAttachmentBtnDiv">&nbsp;</label>
       <div class="slds-form-element__control">
           <apex:outputPanel styleclass="slds-float_right slds-button-group">
               <div id="AddAttachmentBtnDiv">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!addList}" styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand" value="Add Option"
                       onclick="removeOption();">
                   </apex:commandLink>
               </div>
           </apex:outputPanel>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
function removeOption(){
var selectedList = document.getElementById('selectedList');
selectedList.options[selectedList.selectedIndex].remove();
}
```

--- Controller Code-----

```
    public List<SelectOption> getMSPicklist {
get{
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
for( Schema.PicklistEntry obj : APSMultiList__c.Environmental_Concern__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
options.add(new SelectOption(obj.getValue(), obj.getLabel()));
} 
return options;
}  
set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ID's That way: You will have to drill down from the page source.

Initially, it should start from the page (Marked in stars for ref):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" **id="picklist-page"**>
    <apex:form **id="picklist-page-form"**>
        <apex:selectlist id="selectedList" value="{!countries1}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
        </apex:selectlist>
</apex:page>
```

and to access the element you can use 
document.getElementById('picklist-page:picklist-page-form:selectedList')

This would return an array then you can carry on your DOM manipulations.

I hope this Helps!!!